# Hiding a particular row if the value of the column in database is null in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am fetching the data from sql table. All the data is fetching correctly if their is no condition, but if the gap_amounts column value is null in database then while fetching the data and display in front end that gap amounts row should be hided it should not be displayed in front end if the value of gap_amounts is null then.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 0)
{
echo 'Your Application  status is pending from ADMIN';
}
else
  {
 $querys = " 
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
 WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user]' 
   AND user_password = '$_SESSION[password]' 
   AND enrollment_fee_amounts !='' 
   AND bci_collection_funds!=''
";
 $results = mysqli_query($conn, $querys);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){
   $output .= '
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Payment Category</th>
        <th>Account Name</th>
        <th>Account No</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Download Challan</th>               
    </tr>
</thead>
 ';
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
  {
  $output .= '
 <tr class="cha">
<td>1</td>
<td>Application Fee & Stamp Duty</td>
<td>' . $rows['application_fee_account_name'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['application_fee_account_number'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['application_fee_amount'].'</td>                                      
<td><a class="buttons edit" href="generate.php?id=' .$rows['users_id'] .'">VIEW</a></td>                                      
</tr>
<tr class="cha">
<td>4</td>
<td>Library Fund</td>
<td>' . $rows['library_fund_account_name'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['library_fund_account_number'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['library_fund_amount'].'</td>                                     
<td><a class="buttons edit" href="librarygenerate.php?id=' .$rows['users_id'] .'">VIEW</a></td>                                   
</tr>
<tr class="cha">
<td>7</td>
<td>GAP Amount</td>
<td>' . $rows['gap_amount_account_name'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['gap_amount_account_number'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['gap_amounts'].'</td>                                     
<td><a class="buttons edit" href="gapamountgenerate.php?id=' .$rows['users_id'] .'">VIEW</a></td>                                     
</tr>
 ';
   } 
    echo $output;
   }
   else{
 echo "Record Was not Activated.Will be Notified Once Record is Activated through Email And Notification.";
     }
     }
```

Comment: Just don't fetch the data... add `AND gap_amounts IS NOT NULL` to your query

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a condition if gap_amounts is null

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
$output .= '
<tr class="cha">
<td>1</td>
<td>Application Fee & Stamp Duty</td>
<td>' . $rows['application_fee_account_name'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['application_fee_account_number'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['application_fee_amount'].'</td>                                      
<td><a class="buttons edit" href="generate.php?id=' .$rows['users_id'] .'">VIEW</a></td>                                      
</tr>
<tr class="cha">
<td>4</td>
<td>Library Fund</td>
<td>' . $rows['library_fund_account_name'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['library_fund_account_number'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['library_fund_amount'].'</td>                                     
<td><a class="buttons edit" href="librarygenerate.php?id=' .$rows['users_id'] .'">VIEW</a></td>                                   
</tr>';

if ($rows['gap_amounts'] == null || $rows['gap_amounts'] == '') {

} else {
$output .='<tr class="cha">
<td>7</td>
<td>GAP Amount</td>
<td>' . $rows['gap_amount_account_name'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['gap_amount_account_number'].'</td>
<td>' . $rows['gap_amounts'].'</td>                                     
<td><a class="buttons edit" href="gapamountgenerate.php?id=' .$rows['users_id'] .'">VIEW</a></td>                                     
</tr>';

}


} 
echo $output;
}
else{
echo "Record Was not Activated.Will be Notified Once Record is Activated through Email And Notification.";
}
}
```

Comment: No it is displaying gap amounts row

Comment: Hi. I have updated my answer. You may add condition if gap_amounts is null.

Comment: Its not displaying anything after adding the code

Comment: I have added at the table row in gap amounts

Comment: Hi. I have updated the answer for more visualization of the code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi thank you its working fine.Tank you so much